# Python CMA-ES Algorithm to solve user-defined function and constraints

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, genetic, deap

I am struggling to create a simple example of a [CMA-ES](https://www.lri.fr/~hansen/cmaesintro.html) optimization algorithm in python. What is the most streamlined way to optimize the function `x**2 + 2*y**2 -4*x*y - 0.5*y`, subject to constraints `-2<x<2` and `-1<2*(x**2)*y<1`, using the CMA-ES algorithm?

I looked into the DEAP library, but was not able to develop a cohesive attempt. I found [their documentation](https://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples/cmaes.html) less than intuitive. I also looked into the [cma](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cma) package, but it is not clear to me how I can implement constraints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the python `cma` package you can specify bound constraints:

```
import cma
opts = cma.CMAOptions()
opts.set("bounds", [[-2, None], [2, None]])
cma.fmin(cost_function, x_start, sigma_start, opts)
```

For the second constraint, as it has been said before, it is not straightforward, but you can indeed assign high fitness values to out-of-domain candidate solutions. You would just have to tune `cost_function` here. These values can be very high (higher than any function value in the feasible domain) or depend on the constraint violation value.

There are [several methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_method) to handle constraint with penalties. In you case (small dimension) you can try with the simplest one.

Answer (score 3):

I see your struggle with the DEAP docs. Nevertheless, I have written my own Evolutionary Computing library, and lately I have been using DEAP for many proof-of-concepts and I think they did a good job with it.

Going on, Let's take a look at [the complete example](https://github.com/DEAP/deap/blob/master/examples/es/cma_minfct.py). If you read the docs you will be confortable looking at the code. The problem size is the number of variables, so in your case if I understand correctly you would have `N = 2` (x and y).

And you need your custom fitness function instead of `benchamrks.rastrigin`:

`toolbox.register("evaluate", myownfunction)`

The constraints are not implemented, but are an easy task. In the fitness function you can invalidate the individuals that violate the constraints (for instance by assigning a very high fitness, if minimizing) and in few generations your population should be free of invalids.

This would be the simplest approach with DEAP, but the [`deap.cma.Strategy` class](http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/algo.html?highlight=deap.cma#deap.cma.Strategy) can be extended in order to override/extend any method, for instance, the `generate` method so that all the individuals in the initial population are valid.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on how to implement constraints for someone who is not familiar with genetic algorithms, specifically CMAES? For instance, I would like to use pybrain to implement [CMAES optimization](http://pybrain.org/docs/tutorial/optimization.html#continuous-optimization), but it does not tell how to do constrained optimization that involves something like `1 - sum(x_guess)>0`

Comment: What I suggest is to implement the constraints on the fitness evaluation (on which you can deem an individual as invalid if some constraint is not met, by attributing for instance a very high fitness). You can also implement custom operators that will variate the individuals inside given boundaries only. The former is preferable in my opinion, and should be less expensive.